# Tinyhawk 2 has 2 USB profiles HELP

Tags: betaflight

I recently got an emax Tinyhawk 2 rtf kit, and have been flying it around for a few days. I had messed about in a sim and decided to try the tinyhawk in acro mode, only to find that the rates are way different from the sim. I decided to try and change the rates in betaflight, only to find that the drone wouldn't connect.

Upon downloading Zadig and trying to fix the problem, I found that the drone came up as two separate devices under the list:

- Betaflight STM32F411 (Interface 0)
- Betaflight STM32F411 (Interface 1)

I switched both of them to winUSB.

They still declined to connect.

I then tried using the ImpulseRC driver fixer, only for the program to continue searching for the flight controller and never finding anything.

Upon further research I realized I may need to change the drivers in device manager to a COM port.
For one of the two devices, it would switch and change into a COM5 port after updating it to  "USB Serial device"
Even with it a COM port betaflight still declined to connect.

For the other one, the option for usb serial device doesn't show under any of the tabs at all.

I tried multiple USB cords as well to no avail.

Is there anything I am missing here? I am an absolute beginner, and this is my first fpv drone. If you have any suggestions please let me know in the simplest words possible, I know pretty much nothing.